# Facebook and JWT Auth w/ Laravel back-end and React Native app

Tags: laravel, react-native, jwt, facebook-login, dingo-api

I have built a website with vuejs front-end and laravel back-end.

Only way to login is via Facebook Login using Socialite

All that works fine.

Now I am building some React Native apps (Ios/Android) that also use Facebook login but need to interact with the same web api.

I want to use JWT to secure the API for React Native -> Laravel API

I set up JWT w/ Dingo on Laravel side and I am able to generate a token using the JWTAuth::fromUser(). And I have established some API endpoints that use the token to authenticate.. so far so good.

Now here's the part that becomes sticky. I understand that on the Laravel side of things you can create JWT token with *any* user.. right now the JWT "identifier" is simply "id".. and it's my understanding that the token I generate from JWTAuth::fromUser() simply has no idea or care that this user doesn't have conventional credentials and instead used a Facebook Login.

On the React Native side however.. when a new user first authenticates via the Facebook Login.. it has no idea what the "matching user" is on the Laravel app, all I have to go on is basically the unique Facebook Provider Id.

So the question is as follows:

How can I generate a JWT token on the React Native side using only the Facebook Provider Id and the JWT Secret, and more importantly, how do I modify my JWT code on the Laravel side so that it can understand tokens that were generated with the Facebook Provider Id and JWT Token

In other words, I think my Laravel JWT implementation needs to be modified so that tokens are created/parsed purely on the basis of the Facebook Provider Id because otherwise it won't match up with tokens generated on the React Native side.

Many thanks!!

Comment: When I've implemented Facebook logins before, I request the user's name, email, etc from Facebook, and then create a user account in the database, with their unique Facebook App ID associated with the account. Then when re-authenticating in the future, you get their ID again, and find the corresponding account in your database and load that user.

Answer (score 13):

Ok after doing some reading I think this flow might work. Your thoughts please?

1 User authenticates via Facebook on in on Android/Ios app

2 Retrieve facebook access token

3 Do api call to public endpoint on web server and pass FB Access Token and FB ID

4a Web server makes Facebook Graph Api call w/ Access Token and verifies token is valid, is authenticated with Facebook App, and matches Facebook ID

4b If user doesn't exist on web first.. create user

5 If above matches, then web servers generates JWT token from user model and returns JWT token to app

6 App now uses JWT token for future API calls

Comment: Thx for sharing !

Comment: How do you get the token from the app?

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper There are pacakages to get that done. If you are using expo, you can simply use https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook